# Using MediaRecorder in Safari on iOS outputs 0-byte files

Tags: javascript, html, ios

I would like to make a video with the audio of the <video> and the <canvas> capture.
This works fine with Google Chrome on Windows, but Safari on iOS outputs a 0-byte file.

Source code with unintended behavior

```
recorder_stream=new MediaStream();

var audioCtx=new AudioContext();
var source=audioCtx.createMediaElementSource(document.getElementById("main_video"));
var destination=audioCtx.createMediaStreamDestination();
source.connect(destination);
recorder_stream.addTrack(destination.stream.getTracks()[0]);

recorder_stream.addTrack(document.getElementById("main_canvas").captureStream().getTracks()[0]);

recorder=new MediaRecorder(recorder_stream,options);
recorder.ondataavailable=function(e){
    var videoBlob=new Blob([e.data],{type:e.data.type});
    blobUrl=window.URL.createObjectURL(videoBlob);
    document.getElementById("video_download_button").download="video."+filetype;
    document.getElementById("video_download_button").href=blobUrl;
    document.getElementById("video_download_button").style="display:block;";
    alert("finished!");
}
```

No audio, but code that works correctly

```
recorder=new MediaRecorder(document.getElementById("main_canvas").captureStream(),options);
recorder.ondataavailable=function(e){
    var videoBlob=new Blob([e.data],{type:e.data.type});
    blobUrl=window.URL.createObjectURL(videoBlob);
    document.getElementById("video_download_button").download="video."+filetype;
    document.getElementById("video_download_button").href=blobUrl;
    document.getElementById("video_download_button").style="display:block;";
    alert("finished!");
}
```

Comment: Check out my answer here: https://stackoverflow.com/a/76924896/5832236