# MediaRecorder Recording MediaStream With AudioContext Inconsistently Triggering Stop & OnDataAvailable Events On Mobile

Tags: javascript, angular, web-audio-api, mediarecorder, mediastream

I have code that records the stream of a video manipulated and displayed on a `canvas` element and combines it with the `AudioContext` stream of the same video to give it sound.

It works 100% of the time on Desktop. However, on mobile (Safari & Chrome) it works about 50% of the time when it has the `AudioContext` attached and 100% of the time when it does not.

I am using Angular 15 / Ionic 6.

Here is my code. I set up the `MediaStream` by adding the `AudioContext` stream and the video canvas stream as tracks. Then I use this stream in a `MediaRecorder`. When I start the `MediaRecorder` I begin to manipulate each frame of the video and display it on the canvas until the `MediaRecorder` seems to automatically stop when the video ends.

HTML (the click event triggers processing and connection of the `AudioContext`):

```
      <ion-button (click)="startVideoProcessing()">Process Video</ion-button>
      <video id="uploadedVideo" #uploadedVideo autoplay webkit-playsinline playsinline></video>
      <canvas id="canvasVideo" #canvasVideo></canvas>
      <canvas id="segmentationMaskCanvasVideo" #segmentationMaskCanvasVideo></canvas>
```

Setting up the `MediaRecorder`:

```
async videoProcessing() {
    // audioContext: AudioContext;
    // sourceNode: MediaElementAudioSourceNode;
    this.stream = new MediaStream(
      [...this.videoCanvas.captureStream(30).getVideoTracks(),
        this.getAudioTrack()
      ]);
    const options = {
        audioBitsPerSecond: 128000,
        videoBitsPerSecond: 2500000,
        mimeType: this.mimeType,
    };
    // recorder: MediaRecorder
    this.recorder = new MediaRecorder(this.stream, options);
    this.recorder.start();
    this.recorder.ondataavailable = (event) => {
        if (event.data && event.data.size > 0) {
            this.chunks.push(event.data);
        }
    };
    this.recorder.onerror = (event) => {
      console.error(event);
      throw new Error(event.toString());
    };
    this.recorder.onstop = () => {
      const videoBlob = new Blob(this.chunks, { type: this.mimeType });
      const videoFile = new File([videoBlob], this.mimeType === 'video/mp4' ? 'video-green-screen.mp4' : 'video-green-screen.webm', { type: this.mimeType });
      this.fileSelected.emit(videoFile);
    };
    this.registerVideoFrameCallback();
  }

  getAudioTrack() {
    if ((this.video as any).captureStream) {
      // videoAudioTrack: MediaStreamTrack 
      this.videoAudioTrack = (this.video as any).captureStream().getAudioTracks()[0];
    } else if ((this.video as any).mozCaptureStream) {
      this.videoAudioTrack = (this.video as any).mozCaptureStream().getAudioTracks()[0];
    } else {
      const destination = this.audioContext.createMediaStreamDestination();
      this.sourceNode.connect(destination);
      this.videoAudioTrack = destination.stream.getAudioTracks()[0];
    }
    return this.videoAudioTrack;
  }
```

Other TS keeping relevant code:

```
  initVideoElements() {
    this.video = this.videoElementRef.nativeElement;
    this.video.style.display = 'none';
    this.videoCanvas = this.videoCanvasElementRef.nativeElement;
    this.videoCanvas.style.display = 'none';
    this.videoCanvasCtx = this.videoCanvas.getContext('2d');
    this.segmentationMaskCanvas = this.segmentationMaskCanvasElementRef.nativeElement;
    this.segmentationMaskCanvasCtx = this.segmentationMaskCanvas.getContext('2d');
    this.segmentationMaskCanvas.style.display = 'none';
  }

  onVideoFileSelected(file: File) {
    this.videoFile = file; // videoFile: File;
  }

  async startVideoProcessing() {
    // @ViewChild('uploadedVideo', { static: false }) videoElementRef: ElementRef<HTMLVideoElement>;
    // video: HTMLVideoElement;
    this.video.src = URL.createObjectURL(this.videoFile);
    this.silenceVideoAudio();
    this.video.onloadeddata = async () => {
      await this.videoProcessing();
    };
    this.video.onended = async () => {
      this.recorder.stop()
    };
  }

  // This method connects the AudioContext and puts the gain at 0 since I hide the videos with CSS
  silenceVideoAudio() {
    this.audioContext = new AudioContext();
    this.sourceNode = this.audioContext.createMediaElementSource(this.video);
    const gainNode = this.audioContext.createGain();
    gainNode.gain.value = 0;
    this.sourceNode.connect(gainNode);
    gainNode.connect(this.audioContext.destination);
  }

  registerVideoFrameCallback(): void {
      const doSomethingWithTheFrame = (now: number, metadata: any) => {
        this.processingProgress = parseFloat(metadata.mediaTime.toFixed(2)) / this.video.duration;
        this.cdRef.detectChanges();
        this.imageSegmenter.segmentForVideo(this.video, metadata.presentedFrames, async segmentationMask => await this.segmentationVideoCallback(segmentationMask));
      this.videoElementRef.nativeElement.requestVideoFrameCallback(doSomethingWithTheFrame);
      };
      this.video.currentTime = 0;
      this.videoElementRef.nativeElement.requestVideoFrameCallback(doSomethingWithTheFrame);
  }

  async segmentationVideoCallback(segmentationMask){
    // Callback function that segments the video onto the canvas that I capture the stream of
    await this.drawSegmentationResult(segmentationMask.categoryMask);
  }
```

When I check consoles it seems the `MediaRecorder` is going `inactive` by the time the video `onended` is hit. When it goes `inactive` it seems it triggers the `ondataavailable` and `onstop` 100% of the time on desktop, but on mobile with audio it only happens some times. When it does happen I have all of the data necessary.

One thing I tried was `requestData()` on every `requestVideoFrameCallback` but the `ondataavailable` listener was equally unreliable. I would see it get into a conditional to call it, and the recorder was `recording` but the event listener would not be triggered.

Other things I tried were to wrap various parts in `runOutsideAngular` to make sure it wasn't tripped up by the zone, adding a timeslice in `start()`, using `addEventListener`, attempting to stop all tracks previous to `stop()`, and more. None of this consistently worked for me on mobile when an `AudiContext` was attached.

There are no errors logged with `onerror` but this could just also not be firing when it should?

One thing I noticed as well is that sometimes it would not trigger, but when I close my lock screen or other similar events and then come back, it has triggered the event (maybe as a result of something that was hanging on being canceled even when `inactive`?)

**Can anyone help me figure out how to consistently end up with a file that is made up of the altered video canvas stream and the audio from the original video? Either using the `MediaRecorder` as I am here or otherwise?**

Comment: To be clear, when you say "mobile devices", it's always iphones? In such a case, Chrome for iOS is actually based on Safari, so it's normal they behave the same.

Comment: Yesterday I tried removing the audio/video bits/second to see if that was messing it up but it didn't work. Today I may try playing around with `autoplay` off and moving the attachment of everything to when the user selects the file and then using `load()` / `play()` / `start()` when the user clicks `Start Processing`. This instead of attaching /  setting up / playing / starting on the `Start Processing` button click.

Comment: Tried to move things around as I said in my previous comment. That fixed the issues on Chrome and it consistently called recorder.onstop on Safari but the file was made with size 0 so no bytes were pushed, again only when I try to add audio. Starting to think it is an order of events and user interactions issue?

Comment: Ended up being an order of events and race condition issue from what I could tell after I fixed the issues on mobile Chrome.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you are experiencing any of these symptoms with your `MediaRecorder` on mobile devices:

1. File size of `0` / `MediaRecorder` outputting 0 bytes
2. No sound on the final output of the `MediaRecorder`
3. Inconsistent results of the `MediaRecorder` finishing
4. `MediaRecorder` not starting

Then I would suggest you do a few things to correct the issue:

1. First check that your code abides by all the rules of playing media on mobile devices. This answer details and provides links well: https://stackoverflow.com/a/76924896/5832236
2. Secondly check that all of your processes are happening in the order they should be and everything is loaded properly before dependencies. `MediaRecorder` has quite a few rules on when it goes `inactive` and when it will output data. Here is some information on what exactly those conditions are with special note of the `start()`, `stop()`, and `state` methods/properties: https://www.w3.org/TR/mediastream-recording/#mediarecorder-methods

The answer to this problem was mostly related to check 2 after refactoring mobile for check 1. This issue was being caused by the order of events & async code & what I believe was effectively a race condition.

Here is the final code that I used to correct the issue above. The biggest changes were that I broke out a lot of the logic into smaller methods and made sure they executed fully, removed `autoplay` because of the tighter mobile restrictions, used `this.video.load()` after setting the `video.src`, awaited `this.video.play()`, moved my `this.recorder.start()` to begin AFTER starting the `requestVideoFrameCallback` processing.

HTML:

```
<ion-button (click)="startProcessingA()">Process Video</ion-button>
<video id="uploadedVideo" #uploadedVideo webkit-playsinline playsinline></video>
<canvas id="canvasVideo" #canvasVideo></canvas>
<canvas id="segmentationMaskCanvasVideo" #segmentationMaskCanvasVideo></canvas>
```

TS:

```
  initVideoElements() {
    this.video = this.videoElementRef.nativeElement;
    this.video.style.display = 'none';
    this.videoCanvas = this.videoCanvasElementRef.nativeElement;
    this.videoCanvas.style.display = 'none';
    this.videoCanvasCtx = this.videoCanvas.getContext('2d');
    this.segmentationMaskCanvas = this.segmentationMaskCanvasElementRef.nativeElement;
    this.segmentationMaskCanvasCtx = this.segmentationMaskCanvas.getContext('2d');
    this.segmentationMaskCanvas.style.display = 'none';
  }

  async onVideoFileSelected(file: File) {
    this.video.src = URL.createObjectURL(file);
    this.video.onended = async () => {
      this.recorder.stop();
      URL.revokeObjectURL(this.video.src);
    };
    this.video.load();
    if (this.isDesktop) {
      this.startProcessingA();
    }
  }

  async startProcessingA() {
    await this.silenceVideoAudio();
    await this.setupStreamRecorder();
    await this.setupImageSegmenter();
    await this.video.play();
    this.registerVideoFrameCallback();
  }

  async silenceVideoAudio() {
    return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
      this.audioContext = new AudioContext();
      this.sourceNode = this.audioContext.createMediaElementSource(this.video);
      const gainNode = this.audioContext.createGain();
      gainNode.gain.value = 0;
      this.sourceNode.connect(gainNode);
      gainNode.connect(this.audioContext.destination);
      resolve(null);
    });
  }

  registerVideoFrameCallback(): void {
      const doSomethingWithTheFrame = (now: number, metadata: any) => {
        if (this.recorder.state !== 'recording') {
          this.recorder.start();
        }
        this.imageSegmenter.segmentForVideo(this.video, metadata.presentedFrames, async segmentationMask => await this.segmentationVideoCallback(segmentationMask));
        this.video.requestVideoFrameCallback(doSomethingWithTheFrameNotFirefox);
      };
      this.video.currentTime = 0;
      this.video.requestVideoFrameCallback(doSomethingWithTheFrameNotFirefox);
  }

  async setupStreamRecorder() {
    return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
      this.stream = new MediaStream();
      this.stream.addTrack(this.getAudioTrack());
      this.stream.addTrack(this.videoCanvas.captureStream(30).getVideoTracks()[0]);
      const options = {
          mimeType: this.mimeType
      };
      this.recorder = new MediaRecorder(this.stream, options);
      this.recorder.ondataavailable = (event) => {
          if (event.data && event.data.size > 0) {
              this.chunks.push(event.data);
          }
      };
      this.recorder.onerror = (event) => {
        console.error(event);
        throw new Error(event.toString());
      };
      this.recorder.onstop = () => {
        const videoBlob = new Blob(this.chunks, { type: this.mimeType });
        const videoFile = new File([videoBlob], this.mimeType === 'video/mp4' ? 'video-name.mp4' : 'video-name.webm', { type: this.mimeType });
      };
      resolve(null);
    });
  }

  getAudioTrack() {
    const destination = this.audioContext.createMediaStreamDestination();
    this.sourceNode.connect(destination);
    this.videoAudioTrack = destination.stream.getAudioTracks()[0];
    return this.videoAudioTrack;
  }
```